# Computed fields on a GraphQL Schema or Query with Apollo Client

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

I have a GraphQL query that returns two fields, `titleDe` and `titleFr`, representing a title of a post in two different languages.

I would like to have a third field on client-side (so probably local state defined) to store the title for the current language in `title`. My application should then be able to always call `title` only and get the title in the current language.

Is there an equivalent of computed fields in Apollo (Local State) or GraphQL which would allow me to call `title`, which checks what locale is set globally in Apollo Local State (so another query) and then return `titleDe` or `titleFr` based on that?

I didn't work that much with GraphQL and Apollo yet. I know how to solve this in other local state managers e.g. NgRx, Vuex, Redux with the concept of getters/selectors.

My goal is to abstract the titleDe/Fr logics from my applications components., so they don't require the model with all language properties and can only call the simplified `title` property, which will return the correct string based on the global set locale.

Answer (score 4):

You can add additional fields easily using Apollo local state. From the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state#client-fields-resolvers):

> Local resolvers are very similar to remote resolvers. Instead of sending your GraphQL query to a remote GraphQL endpoint, which then runs resolver functions against your query to populate and return a result set, Apollo Client runs locally defined resolver functions against any fields marked with the @client directive.

Here's a simple example:

```
const GET_LOCALE = gql`
  query GetLocale {
    locale @client
  }
`;

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link,
  resolvers: {
    Article: { // or whatever your actual type is called
      title: (article, _args, { cache }) => {
        const { locale } = cache.readQuery({ query: GET_LOCALE });
        switch (locale) {
          case 'de': return article.titleDe
          case 'fr': return article.titleFr
        }
      },
    },
  },
});

// Initialize the cache after creating it
cache.writeData({
  data: {
    locale: getPreferenceOrProvideDefault(),
  },
});
```

Here we store `locale` in local state as well, and use `readQuery` to fetch it inside our resolver. However, you could also directly fetch the preference from somewhere else (like `localStorage`) instead.

Note that you will still need to request these fields as part of your query -- i.e. your `title` field will not be expanded to the appropriate set of server-side fields.